# Matplotlib - how to direct subplot with .set_data to correct subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, while-loop, time-series, axes

I am working on a project where I need to update real time plots in Python. Now I am running into the exercise of plotting multiple time series in different windows.

More precisely, I have three time series `line1`, `line2` and `line3` which I want to plot in a dynamically updating plot. Now I need two things:

**First**

`line1` and `line2` should be shown on the first axis `axes_1` and the third time series (which is the sum of the other two) should be shown on the second axis `axes_2`. As for now, all time series are plotted on axes_2.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

n = 1000
x = np.NaN
y1 = np.NaN
y2 = np.NaN
y3 = np.NaN

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=x, value=y1, value2=y2, value3=y3), index=np.arange(n)) # not neccessarily needed to have a pandas df here, but I like working with it.
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']) #format 'time' as datetime object

# initialise plot and line
fig = plt.figure()
G = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1)

axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[0, :])
axes_1.set_ylabel('line1 and 2')
axes_1.set_title("This plot shows line1 and line2")

axes_2 = plt.subplot(G[1, :])
axes_2.set_ylabel('line3')
axes_2.set_title("This plot shows line3")

#axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = plt.plot(df['time'], df['value'])
line2, = plt.plot(df['time'], df['value2'])
line3, = plt.plot(df['time'], df['value3'])

i=0

# simulate line drawing
while i <= n:
    #generate random data point
    newData = np.random.rand()
    newData2 = newData + 1

    # extend the data frame by this data point and attach the current time as index
    df.loc[i, "value"] = newData
    df.loc[i, "value2"] = newData2
    df.loc[i, "value3"] = newData + newData2

    df.loc[i, "time"] = pd.datetime.now()

    # plot values against indices, use autoscale_view and relim to readjust the axes
    line1.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(100)), df['value'][:i].tail(100))
    line2.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(100)), df['value2'][:i].tail(100))
    line3.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(100)), df['value3'][:i].tail(100))

    axes_1.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    axes_1.relim()

    axes_2.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    axes_2.relim()

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.00000000001)

    # add to iteration counter
    i += 1

    print(i)
```

Running this on Python 2.7 produces the following plot

[image]

**Second**

I need the x axis to be properly formatted from numerical to readable time format

Comment: use `axes_1.plot`, not `plt.plot` and look at the many other questions on SO about formatting datetime axes

Comment: Thanks, the axes_1.plot worked